# C reinitialize array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, memset

Let's say I initialize an array like this:

```
char array[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Then I modify that array by writing some data to it so in the end it looks like this:

```
array[] = {1, 42, 32, 16, 89};
```

If I want to re-initialize the same array back to zeros so I can use that same array again, would it be correct to do so in this way?:

```
memset(array, 0, 5);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, but `memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));` would be better, that you do not need to keep track of the size of the array if you change the size to e.g. 6 later.

Comment: The third parameter have to be `sizeof(array)`. That's for the case when `sizeof array[0]` is bigger than 1 (e.g. if having `int array[]`). `memset` takes the number of bytes.

Comment: Just to add: Careful when `memset`ting anything else than a `char` array. Even more if setting to other than`0`. This becasue `memset` works on `char []` and has no concept about the actual type of the array.

Comment: @Olaf, can you use memset on `unsigned char`?

Comment: Did you end your answer with "or even better" without any following text intentionally?

Comment: @cad not intentionally :)

Answer (score 2):

> [...] would it be correct to do so in this way?

**Yes**.